# How to write a query in Mongo to remove records where DateTimeOffset is greater than 30 days

Tags: mongodb, datetimeoffset, robo3t

[A capture from mongoDb with the structure of a Date time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv2UR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set TTL indexes while creating your records.TTL indexes are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time.

To create a TTL index, use the **db.collection.createIndex()** method with the expireAfterSeconds option on a field whose value is either a date or an array that contains date values.

For example, to create a TTL index that removes the record after 30 days on the createdDate field of the User collection, use the following operation in the mongo shell:

```
db.User.createIndex( { "createdDate": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 2592000 } )
```

**src:** https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/